# How to show rigorously that $\lim\limits_{x \to -3+} \frac{x-2}{(x^2)(x+3)} = -\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am a first year undergraduate (prospective math major) and I am taking an introduction to Calculus course. Every week we are assigned a set of questions and this week we were asked to determine $$\lim\limits_{x \to -3+} \frac{x-2}{(x^2)(x+3)}$$

I relied on my intuition and said that the answer was $-\infty$ but I wanted to try and produce a rigorous proof. I first started thinking about what it means for $$\lim\limits_{x \to -3+} \frac{x-2}{(x^2)(x+3) }=-\infty$$

and I thought that I need to show that

> For all $M<0 $ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $-3<x<\delta-3 \implies \frac{x-2}{(x^2)(x+3)}<M$

I tried playing around with other definitions and tried to produce my own proof, but I am not getting anywhere. Am I thinking of this correctly? I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: It seem to me you can take $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$. (But you should show that it is less than $M$, not $-M$, as $M<0$).

Comment: I made a mistake when typing out the Question. It should be M not -M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impose that $\delta < 1$,

Suppose $-3 < x < -3 + \delta$, then

$$x-2 < -5+\delta< -4$$

$$x^2 > 9, $$

That is so far we have $$\frac{x-2}{x^2(x+3)}< \frac{-4}{9(x+3)}$$

We want to solve for $$-\frac{4}{9(x+3)}< M$$

$$\frac{4}{9(x+3)}> - M$$

If we pick $\delta < \min(\frac{-4}{9M},1)$, then we have 
$$x+3 < \min(\frac{-4}{9M},1)$$
$$\frac{1}{x+3}> \frac{1}{\min(\frac{-4}{9M},1)}$$

$$-\frac{4}{9(x+3)} <  \frac{-4}{\min(\frac{-4}M,9)}$$

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2(x+3)}< \frac{-4}{9(x+3)} < \frac{-4}{\min(-\frac{4}M,9)}< M$$